# Why do Harvester Queens have mouths?

Tags: independence-day, independence-day-resurgence

In the first film Doctor Oken, having studied the Harvesters who crashed on Roswell, theorizes that they communicated with each other telepathically as they had no vocal cords and we don't see mouths on them either.

At the start of *Resurgence* we see when the Queen of the Second Mother Ship picks up the distress signal from the first there she seems to yell (sorrow that she lost a follow queen or anger that humans killed it) and we see she has a mouth with teeth. We see this again when the Queen is killed and she lands in front of the school bus.

Assuming that the Harvester that Steve and David were waving to wasn't a Queen (as we see that it doesn't have a mouth when it watches the Nukes timer), why do Queens have mouths while the rest of the species doesn't? If the Harvester that Steve and David was waving was a Queen then why does the Queen of the Second Mother Ship has a mouth and not the first?

Comment: So they can yell at people.